# Set ImageView colorFilter on android 5 (api 21)

Tags: android, imageview, android-5.0-lollipop

I have weird problem with ImageView on android 5(api 21).
When I set ImageView tint color in xml then I can’t change it on code!!!
I tried several ways to change the colorFilter of ImageView programmatically but it doesn’t work.
I have this problem only on api 21.
Any idea?

Comment: What ways did you tried so far?

Comment: What if you just don't set the initial color in XML? Can we see your code?

Comment: If i remove initial tint color that would work like a charm but then i need to put so many if else conditions in so many of my recycler adapters. i think this is the only way that i can handle this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After searching lots of hours i found out this is a bug in api 21 that when you setting initialization tint color to `ImageView` or `ImageButton` you can't change it in code later.
The best solution is moving initial tint color to code to prevent this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.COLOR_YOUR_COLOR), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: It changes the color for i think nearly 10 milliseconds then back to xml set tint.

Comment: I'v tried this in 2 devices and 1 emulator running android 5.0.2